# SQL Server non-clustered index and the query optimizer

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

In one of the projects I am working on, there is a table which has about one million records. For better performance I created a non-clustered index and defined **sid** field as **index key column**. When I execute this query

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[sid]
      ,[idm]
      ,[origin]
      ,[status]
      ,[pid]
  FROM [EpollText_Db].[dbo].[PhoneNumbers] where sid = 9
```

[image]

The execution plan is like the above picture. My question is, why does SQL server ignore the **sid index** and scan the whole one million records instead, to find the query result. Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Optimizer advices to create the  index on the column. Are you sure the index was created in the DB you are querying?

Comment: yes the DB is EpollText_Db @Serg

Comment: Copy the optimizer's recommended DDL and try to execute it. What is the result?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know where to find it ? @Serg

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: you're right. I remove the first image but the second one is hard to explain @DaleK

Comment: `CREATE INDEX` DDL follows "MIssing index.."

Comment: Provide DDL of your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is in the size of your result. You are selecting ten thousand records from your database which is quite a lot if you consider the necessary query plan that would include `index seek` operation. The plan includes `index seek` would be something like this

[image]

Therefore, ten thousand key lookups would be included and a significant number of random logical accesses. Due to this, if your table row is small, he could decide to use clustered index scan. If you are really concerned about the performance of this query create a covering index:

```
 CREATE INDEX idx_PhoneNumbers_sid 
    ON [EpollText_Db].[dbo].[PhoneNumbers](sid)
    INCLUDE ([id],[idm],[origin],[status],[pid])
```

However, this may slow down inserts, deletes, and updates, and it may also double the size of your table.